# "viewWillAppear" not call in xcode 4.5 with iPhone 4.3 simulator

Tags: iphone, ios

"viewWillAppear" not call in xcode 4.5 with iphone 4.3 simulator, but if it runs in iPhone 5.0 or iPhone 6.0 simulator, this method will be called.

why? and what can i do if i want to do something when the view of an controller will appear in ios 4.3?

Comment: What action is causing the view to appear?

Comment: i use "pushViewController",so the view will be appear.

Comment: And is the `UINavigationController` presented modally or else the root view controller? What I'm trying to eliminate is the possibility that you've attempted to use child view controllers prior to their official implementation.

Comment: Controller *controller = [[Controller alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES]; 
     i just do like that. but the problem is in fact all the "viewWillAppear" or "viewWillDisappear" methods will not call in xcode4.5 with iPhone 4.3 simulator. but it will be called in iPhone6.0. so i am confuses.

Comment: And was `self.navigationController` presented modally?

Comment: self.navigationController is not presented modally. i use a custom tabbarController.the custom tabbarController just add the views of the controllers one by one. and i try to use the system tabbarController instead.the "viewWillAppear" is called in ios4.3! i think this method is optimized in ios6. so how can i resolve this problem if i want to use custom tabbarController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it may be related to the "View Controller Abusing". Check if your container view controller is used correctly. You can refer to [this post](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/03/09/abusing-uiviewcontrollers/) for detail.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, the problem appears to be the lack of container view controllers in iOS 4. As of 5+ you're explicitly meant to be able to add the `view` of any controller into the view of any other* and that will generate the appropriate `view[Will/Did]Appear`, along with all the other newer messages — `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, etc.

In 4 you weren't explicitly allowed to build container view controllers and there's no deliberate, specific backwards link that connects a view back to its controller.

As a result, when you add the navigation controller to your view it doesn't get `viewDidAppear`. Because it doesn't know that its view has appeared, it doesn't tell any of the controllers it contains that their views have appeared.

Probably the best you're going to be able to do is to hack around that by (i) checking if you're operating under iOS 4; and (ii) if so, posting artificial `viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear/viewWillDisappear/viewDidDisappear` to your contained controllers.

Based on personal experience, iOS 4 (at least in 4.3) does actually implement `addChildViewController:` but not to do what the later, documented version does. So despite it not being an entirely accurate functionality check I tend to use `if([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentingViewController)])` to determine whether I need to propagate these messages manually.

[*] and you should also call `addChildViewController:` to make sure all messages move correctly in all directions